# Why is the factored import statement better?

Tags: go

The official tour of Go, after exhibiting a factored import like this...

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)
```

... [contains the following slightly unclear remark](https://tour.golang.org/basics/2):

> You can also write multiple import statements, like:
>
> ```
> import "fmt"
> import "math"
> ```
>
> But it is good style to use the factored import statement.

Is there actually any concrete advantage to using one approach over the other - such as a difference in behaviour or an easy-to-make typo that is only a danger with one of the two syntaxes - or is this just an arbitrary style convention?

Comment: It's a convenience construct ... same goes with var `var x,y <T> or var(
x <T>
y <T2>
)`

Comment: Well, a member said Go was opinionated to do so: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14428

Answer (score 20):

There is no difference except for the amount of typing you have to do. A good sized program or package can easily have a dozen or more imported packages so why keep typing the same word (`import`) time and again when you can achieve the same with a pair of ().

Though most people probably use [GoImports](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports) nowadays anyway.

Answer (score 7):

There is absolutely no difference for a go compiler. The difference is only for a go programmer in how many times he has to copy/type import. You can look at it in the same way as:

```
func f1(n1, n2, n3 int){
    ...
}
```

vs

```
func f1(n1 int, n2 int, n3 int){
    ...
}
```

or `var n1, n2, n3 int` vs

```
var n1 int
var n2 int
var n3 int
```

both will produce the same result.